# Why does cocos2d return different worldSpace coordinates?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

My understanding is that "worldSpace" means the actual position of a sprite relative to the screens width/height.  In other words, I would expect a sprite at the bottom left of the screen to be something like {x: 0, y: screenHeight - spriteHeight}.

However I have just found that if I have a few nodes and I do:

```
[node1 convertToWorldSpace:sprite.position];
[node2 convertToWorldSpace:sprite.position];
```

If I output these CGPoints, I see:

```
2014-07-13 19:57:39.733 myGame[6642:907] ================> {574.997, 723}
2014-07-13 19:57:39.735 myGame[6642:907] ================> {450, 635}
```

Two completely different coordinates...  What exactly is going on here?  I would expect the world space to be the same coordinates regardless of which node and its positioning...  What am I missing?

Comment: Please show where `node1` and `node2` are on the screen, with a screenshot please.  Your question doesn't have much meaning at the moment.

Comment: its relative to the scene's coordinate system. Only if scene position is 0,0 will conversion result in screen coordinates as well.